# number format in Oracle Business Intelligence (OBIEE) Analysis

Tags: business-intelligence, number-formatting, obiee

how do I set number format in Oracle Business Intelligence (OBIEE) Analysis ?
I mean decimal places and use of 1000 separator. 
Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the criteria tab of your analysis:

1. Click the fact column and select "Column Properties"
2. Click on "Data Format"
3. Check "Override Default Data Format" box
4. Specify decimal places and 1000s separator
5. If you want this format to be applied to all the ocurrences of this fact column (and assuming you have the privileges) you can save this format as system-wide default by clicking "Save as default"

Comment: Victor HDC, great, I'll try it at office. Honestly, I tried to look seems like everywhere. Just by chance, could you please show some print screen of "criteria tab" ? Sorry for disturbing, I'm very new bo OBIEE. Looking forward to see your reply.

Comment: Sure, it looks like this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35214_01/doc/doc.1131/e20362/img/rbiig_obiee_criteria.png  Just click the arrow beside the name of the column and select "Column Properties" from the dropdown menu